# accessing pointer to fortran vector of doubles from multiple locations of C# program

Tags: c#, fortran

I'm working with a C# program that makes calls to a fortran DLL.  The example below shows some working C# code that declares a pointer of type double ("ptr_spf"), initializes it to null, and then passes it into fortran where it is filled (in this case, ptr_spf is pointing to a vector of doubles).  I am then able to loop over the fortran vector of doubles and add each entry to a C# list.  So far so good.

Unfortunately as I've continued to develop the code, I'm realizing that what I've done so far is not sufficient.  Instead, I need to access the contents of ptr_spf from elsewhere in the C# code (different classes).  That is, instead of accessing the statically stored values contained within `SPFLowValues` List, I instead want to work with the updated values being pointed-to by ptr_spf because they are updated  by other calls to the fortran DLL.  My question is this: How do I declare ptr_spf at the top of the class and make it publicly available to other classes within the C# program?  When I attempted to move the declaration of ptr_spf to the top of the class, and define it with `public unsafe double* ptr_spf;`, Visual Studio doesn't like the fact that it is uninitialized when I go to use it (see the screen grab at the end of this post).  Bottom line, is there a way to make a pointer to a vector of fortran doubles publicly available so that I can access it from other parts of the C# program?

**C#**:

```
class cshare_call2fortran {
    // declaration of some variables
    public static List<double> SPFlowValues = new List<double>();
    ...

    // declare comms with fortran DLL
    ...
    [DllImport("libmf6d.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public unsafe static extern int get_value_ptr_double([In] byte[] address,
                               [In, Out] ref double* ptr);
    ...

    // various functions
    ...
    // question pertains to the following function
    public static void get_spflow_ptr()
    {
        int index_spf = individual_varnames.FindIndex(x => x.Contains("INFLOW"));
        var SPFlow_Address = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(individual_varnames[index_spf] + char.MinValue);

        int rank_spf = 0;
        result = get_var_rank(SPFlow_Address, ref rank_spf);
        var shape_spf = new int[rank_spf];
        result = get_var_shape(SPFlow_Address, shape_spf);
        unsafe
        {
            double* ptr_spf = null;
            result = get_value_ptr_double(SPFlow_Address, ref ptr_spf);
            for (int i = 0; i < shape_spf[0]; ++i)
            {
                SPFlowValues.Add(ptr_spf[i]);
                spflow_len++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Fortran** function (included in case it is helpful to see what's going on inside "get_value_ptr_double"):

```
function get_value_ptr_double(c_var_address, c_arr_ptr) result(bmi_status) bind(C, name="get_value_ptr_double")
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: get_value_ptr_double
  character (kind=c_char), intent(in) :: c_var_address(*) !< memory address string of the variable
  type(c_ptr), intent(inout) :: c_arr_ptr                 !< pointer to the array
  integer(kind=c_int) :: bmi_status                       !< BMI status code
  ! local
  character(len=LENMEMPATH) :: mem_path
  character(len=LENVARNAME) :: var_name
  integer(I4B) :: access_type
  logical(LGP) :: found
  real(DP), pointer :: scalar_ptr
  real(DP), dimension(:), pointer, contiguous :: array_ptr
  real(DP), dimension(:,:), pointer, contiguous :: array2D_ptr
  integer(I4B) :: rank    
  
  bmi_status = BMI_FAILURE

  call split_address(c_var_address, mem_path, var_name)
  
  rank = -1
  call get_mem_rank(var_name, mem_path, rank)
  if (rank == 0) then
    call mem_setptr(scalar_ptr, var_name, mem_path)
    c_arr_ptr = c_loc(scalar_ptr)
  else if (rank == 1) then
    call mem_setptr(array_ptr, var_name, mem_path)
    c_arr_ptr = c_loc(array_ptr)
  else if (rank == 2) then
    call mem_setptr(array2D_ptr, var_name, mem_path)
    c_arr_ptr = c_loc(array2D_ptr)
  else
    write(istdout,*) 'BMI Error: unsupported rank for variable '//var_name
    return
  end if

  bmi_status = BMI_SUCCESS    
  
end function get_value_ptr_double
```

The following is a screen grab showing the error when attempting to move the declaration of ptr_spf to the beginning of the class:
[image]

Comment: In the last screenshot, looks like you forgot to declare ptr_spf. It is declared as double* in the version above.

Comment: @RomanPolunin I declared ptr_spf at the top of the class with `public unsafe double* ptr_spf` (as described in the text) but still got the error shown in the screen grab

Comment: Either add "static" to that declaration, or make it a local variable in the method. Otherwise, it is an instance field, which you can't use from inside static method get_spflow_ptr.

Comment: Thank you @RomanPolunin, I was indeed missing "static", and once I added it I was able to retrieve ptr_spf from other classes within the C# program.  Thanks again